# How to convert 1d numpy array to 2d numpy array

Tags: arcpy, numpy, 2d

I used FeatureClassToNumPyArray like this:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(datapath, "lyr_fixpoints", "area_in_m2 > 8000") 
arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray("lyr_fixpoints", ('land_type', 'asset_cat', 'name', 'maintenance'), null_value=-999)  
print arr
```

and get the following 1d array:

```
[(5, 0, 380, 3) (1, 4, 369, 3) (5, 0, 421, 2) (0, 7, 425, 1)]
```

Now I want to convert this array into a 2d array of this form, because the 2d array is very suitable for my further operations.

```
[[5 0 380 3]
 [1 4 369 3]
 [5 0 421 2]
 [0 7 425 1]]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Now that you have an array you seem to be using pure Python so have you searched for your answer at [so]?

Answer (score 1):

I can't specifically comment on ArcPy, as I have never used it. However it seems that you already have a 2-D numpy array with a shape of 4x4 (4 rows and 4 columns):

```
import numpy as np

Array2D = np.array([(5, 0, 380, 3), (1, 4, 369, 3), (5, 0, 421, 2), (0, 7, 425, 1)])
print(Array2D)
print("Array shape =", Array2D.shape)
print("Dimensions =", Array2D.ndim)

Array1D = Array2D.flatten() # Flatten to a 1D array
print(Array1D)
print("Array shape =", Array1D.shape)
print("Dimensions =", Array1D.ndim)
```

The 2D array: Array shape = (4, 4); Dimensions = 2.

The 1D array: Array shape = (16, ); Dimensions = 1.